# Facebook OAuth Leadgen Automation

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I am currently trying to create a webhook to ingest the real time updates for Facebook Leadgen. I want to automate it so that once I set it, I can just let it run without having to do any more manual work.

After I get the webhook ping from Facebook with the Leadgen Id, I can make a request to facebook with an user token or page token: 

`https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/{leadgen-id}?access_token={access_token}`

Since regular tokens expire in about an hour, I have to continually request one from Facebook by using the Login dialog so that I can continually read Leadgen entries.

I know of asking for an extended token, but those expire at some point as well.  Page access tokens seem to expire as well.

Is there any way that a script can be set to automically ingest webhook pings and use the Leadgen id to get information regarding the entry?

Comment: Extended page access tokens do not expire by default. And app access tokens don’t expire at all. Not sure if you can use them for this endpoint though. If you need a user access token, then 60 days validity is the most you can get. After that you will have to get a new one. By debugging the token and checking its expiration time you could set up some kind of notification system, that tells the user they have to generate a new token soon.

Comment: I started by connecting fresh new facebook account so I don't think token would have expired since it was issued less than few hours ago.